# How to fetch embeddedId object in GET call using Spring Data Rest

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-rest

I am using Spring 1.3.3 and I am unable to get the associated object for embedded class using GET. It returns the URI instead of object while using projection.

```
   {
      "employeeId": {
        "empId": 4,
        "_links": {
          "address": {
            "href": "http://localhost:8082/address/1"
          },
          "zipcode": {
            "href": "http://localhost:8082/zipcode/2"
          }
        }
      },
      "empId": 4,
      "name": "ap",

    },
    "_links": {
      "self": {
        "href": "http://localhost:8082/employee/com.blah.blah.Employee@64f11498"
      },
      "adNetworkParam": {
        "href": "http://localhost:8082/employee/com.blah.blah.EmployeeId@64f11498{?projection}",
        "templated": true
      },
      "demandSource": {
        "href": "http://localhost:8082/employee/com.blah.blah.EmployeeId@64f11498/address"
      },
      "targetCharacteristic": {
        "href": "http://localhost:8082/employee/com.blah.blah.EmployeeId@64f11498/zipcode"
      }
    }
  }
```

My domain classes as follows..

Employee.java

@Entity

```
@Table(name = "employee")
public class Employee implements Serializable {
    private EmployeeId employeeId;
    private Address address;
    private Zipcode zipcode;
    private int empId;
    private String name;

    //getter
    ...
    @MapsId("address")
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "address_id")
    public Address getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    @MapsId("zipcode")
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "zipcode_id")
    public Zipcode getZipcode() {
        return zipcode;
    }

    // setter
    .....
```

Address.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name="address")
public class Address implements Serializable {
    private int id;
    private String streetName;
    private String cityName
```

Zipcode.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "zipcode")
public class Zipcode implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private int id;
    private String code;
```

EmployeeId.java

```
@Embeddable
public class EmployeeId implements Serializable {
    private Address address;
    private Zipcode zipcode;
    private int empId;
```

My Projection is as follows,

```
@Projection(name = "employeeProjection", types = { Employee.class })
public interface EmployeeProjection {

    Address getAddress();

    Zipcode getZipcode();

    int getEmpId();

    String getName();
}
```

Employee Search repository class as follows,

```
@RepositoryRestResource(excerptProjection = EmployeeProjection.class)
interface EmployeeRepository extends CrudRepository<Employee, EmployeeId> {
    List<Employee> findByNameContaining(@Param("name") @RequestParam("name") String name);

    Employee findById(@Param("employeeId") @RequestParam("employeeId") Integer employeeId);

}
```

How to return associated object instead of URI for embedded class??

Kindly provide your inputs.

Comment: Please update Spring

Comment: What can I update?? spring version?? or anything else? if version, to which version??

Answer (score 0):

You should use excerpts in your repository definition. I can guess according to your GET result, that the  Employee repository is as following:

```
interface EmployeeRepository extends CrudRepository<Employee, EmployeeId> {}
```

Change it as following:

```
@RepositoryRestResource(excerptProjection = EmployeeProjection.class)
interface EmployeeRepository extends CrudRepository<Employee, EmployeeId> {}
```

This will cause to zipCode and address to be inlined. Note, that links to inlined resources will still appear in the projection.

The employee model should be modified and to be defined with @OneToOne annotation above embedded members:

```
@Table(name = "employee")
public class Employee implements Serializable {
    private EmployeeId employeeId;
    @OneToOne
    private Address address;
    @OneToOne
    private Zipcode zipcode;
    private int empId;
    private String name;
```

You can read more in [spring doc](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/current/reference/html/).

Comment: My code is same as what you are provided. But it is not working for embedded class. But this works fine in a normal class.

Comment: You mean address and zip code? I think you should provide @OneToOne annotation to both.

Comment: Yes. I need only for @ManyToOne annotation. How to configure to return object instead of URI???

Comment: I have updated my entity (Employee.java). Kindly verify and provide your comments.. plz...

Comment: I wonder why it is ManyToOne relationship. Isn't address and zip code just for that employee? ManyToOne is for something, that may be referred by several entities. For example, if you will mention the employer. I suggest you to change the relationship to @OneToOne and test, if a projection is like you mean.

Comment: This is just for a sample. I want to use my application for those relations. Kindly provide your inputs for @ManyToOne entity.

Comment: Remove  MapsId and JoinColumn annotations. Just use ManyToOne. It looks you are trying to do too much things together in one shot.Add things incrementally; reach a simple code working and add the next step in your learning. Good luck.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127045/discussion-between-sst-and-asch).